# Inserting a vertex correction in Feyn - the Lyx Feynman package

Tags: lyx, diagrams, feynmf

I can't seem to be able to draw a standard Feynman diagram and add a vertex correction like here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Feynman_second_order_vertex.svg

When I try, my fermionic lines become disconnected. Help!

Here's my attempt at it:

```
\Diagram{fd &  &  &  &  &  & fu\\
 & \vertexlabel^{q'}fdA &  &  &  & fuA\vertexlabel^{l}\\
 & gv & fd & g\vertexlabel^{W^{\pm}}g & fu\\
 & gv & fu &  & fd\\
 & \vertexlabel^{\bar{q}}fuV &  &  &  & fdV\vertexlabel^{\nu}\\
fu &  &  &  &  &  & fd
}
```

Comment: Which package/module do you load to create create this diagram?

Comment: It's the one included automatically in Lyx: \usepackage{feyn}

Comment: Without a full minimal working example this is very unlikely to get answers: I'm therefore marking as 'unclear'.